# Interior of a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: general-topology

I am studying Munkres topology on my own.

I want to find  the interior of each of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$$A = \{x \times y \mid y = 0\}$$

To find the interior, I want show that if $x \times 0$ be an arbitrary point of $A$, then there does not exists any neighborhood $U$ of $x \times 0$ such that $U \subset A$. And to do that I want to show $U$ be a nbd of $x \times 0$ such that $U \subset A$, then it is a contradiction. Hence $\text{Int } A = \emptyset$.

But I can not execute the above idea. Please help me.

Comment: When you wrote $x\times y$, did you mean $(x,y)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes.

Comment: make use of the basis of standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Then why don't you edit your question?

Answer (score 3):

$A$ is just the entire x-axis according to your definition. Now consider any point on the x axis and try to draw any circle(open ball) having center at that point. It is bound to have points inside it which does not lie on the x axis.

Answer (score 2):

If $(x,0)\in A$, and if $r>0$, then $\left(x,\frac r2\right)\in D_r\bigl((x,0)\bigr)$. But $\left(x,\frac r2\right)\notin A$. So, every open disk centered at $(x,0)$ contains points outside $A$, and therefore $(x,0)\notin\mathring A$. Since this occurs for each element of $A$, $\mathring A=\emptyset$.